# Comentário em tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

É possível inserir um comentário na tabela igual ao comentário em um campo da tabela?

Estou precisando inserir informações de até 160 caracteres nas tabelas do banco de dados para ajudar os outros devs a ter um breve resumo do que se trata cada uma delas, sei fazer em campos mas não encontrei nada sobre as tabelas.

Comment: Um `README.md` junto com os arquivos relacionados não serve?

Comment: Pensei mesmo se é possível como o campo da tabela, mas é prático assim também, mas se houver como fazer isso, gostaria de aprender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um comentário na tabela alterando-a:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela COMMENT = 'Comentário da tabela';
```

E pode ler o comentário com a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tabela';
```

Comment: Isso isso isso, obrigado !!! =)